# Accessing properties from a class in an inherited static method in PHP

Tags: php, class, static

I have a number of PHP classes inheriting a single base class. This base class offers up a static method, let's call it `methodA()` that can be overridden in each class, but in practice won't be overridden very much. Each class has a static variable, let's call it `name` that is different, but `methodA()` needs to be able to act based on `name` differently for each class. I'm new to object oriented PHP, so I'm not exactly sure how best to do this.

In Java I would make a property on the base class and then define it in the constructor method which I would then call via `super()`, but I'm not sure how best to do this based on static data. Am I on the right track? What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php

Comment: FYI: if your code revolves around `static` calls, it's not OOP. What you have are just namespaced globals (variables and functions).

Comment: @AlexBlex if you make that comment into an answer with an example, I'll gladly accept.

Answer (score 0):

This answer was thanks to **@AlexBlex.**

PHP provides a feature called [*Late Static Bindings*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php) that allow exactly this behavior.

> As of PHP 5.3.0, PHP implements a feature called late static bindings which can be used to reference the called class in a context of static inheritance.

In the example provided in the question, the way to do this would be as such:

```
class Base {
    public static function methodA() {
        return static::$name;
    }
}

class A extends Base {
    public static $name = "Apple";
}

class B extends Base {
    public static $name = "Box";
}
```

You can then call the function as such with the expected results:

```
echo(A::methodA()); // "Apple"
echo(B::methodA()); // "Box"
```

This example runs in PHP 7.